# Freeing memory of Linked list (which also contains another Linked list)

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, free

Basically I want to be able to free memory of a linked list (which also contains a linked list), so that the user can enter their own custom values to create a new linked list. I also want my print function to no longer find these values in memory once they have been freed, so maybe the condition (while list_ptr != NULL) is not the correct condition to use while printing?
I have the two following structs:

```
typedef struct item
{
    char name[125];
    struct item *next;
} Item;


typedef struct list
{
    char name[125];
    struct list *next;
    struct list *prev;
    Item *first_item;
} List;
```

I used them to create a linked list using the following function, which loads my default list:

```
void load_default(List **board)
{

    List *list1 = malloc(sizeof(List));
    strcpy(list1->name, "Abey:");
    list1->next = NULL;
    Item *item1_1 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(item1_1->name, "Oculus Pro");
    Item *item1_2 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(item1_2->name, "Oculus Quest 1");
    item1_2->next = NULL;
    list1->first_item = item1_1;
    item1_1->next = item1_2;
    List *list2 = malloc(sizeof(List));
    strcpy(list2->name, "Dante:");
    list2->next = list1;
    Item *item2_1 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(item2_1->name, "Oculus Quest 1");
    item2_1->next = NULL;
    Item *item2_2 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(item2_2->name, "3070 RTX");
    item2_2->next = NULL;
    list2->first_item = item2_1;
    item2_1->next = item2_2;
    List *list3 = malloc(sizeof(List));
    strcpy(list3->name, "Tim:");
    list3->next = list2;
    Item *item3_1 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(item3_1->name, "Oculus Quest 2");
    list3->first_item = item3_1;
    item3_1->next = NULL;
    List *list4 = malloc(sizeof(List));
    strcpy(list4->name, "Nick:");
    Item *item4_1 = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    strcpy(item4_1->name, "3070 RTX");
    item4_1->next = NULL;
    list4->first_item = item4_1;
    list4->next = list3;
    list1->prev = list2;
    list2->prev = list3;
    list3->prev = list4;
    list4->prev = NULL;
    *board = list4;
}
```

I also have a print function:

```
void print_list(List *list)
{
    List *list_ptr = list;

    while (list_ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", list_ptr->name);
        Item *item = list_ptr->first_item;
        while (item != NULL)
        {
            printf("\t%s\n", item);
            item = item->next;
        }
        list_ptr = list_ptr->next;
    }
    printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
    getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

I tried to create a function to free memory but it did not work as expected:

```
void free_lists(List *list)
{
    List *list_ptr = list;
    Item *item;
    while (list_ptr != NULL)
    {
        item = list_ptr->first_item;
        while (item != NULL)
        {
            Item *temp = item;
            free(item);
            item = temp->next;
        }
        List *templis = list_ptr;
        free(list_ptr);
        list_ptr = templis->next;
    }
}
```

While it did free up some bits, I was left with the following:

```
p8w
         p♫w
p8w
         p8w
p8w
         p8w
         3070 RTX
p8w
         p8w
         Oculus Quest 1
```

when i called the print function. Somehow my print function is still finding all the elements, but finding garbage values, or the original values, in those parts of memory.

Comment: Using ("dereferencing") a pointer to dynamic memory after the block has been free'd is undefined... Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these lines,

```c
        while (item != NULL)
        {
            Item *temp = item;
            free(item);
            item = temp->next;
        }
```

`temp` points to `item` by you have previously destroyed whatever `item` was pointing to.

Instead, it should point to `item->next`.

```c
        while (item != NULL)
        {
            Item *temp = item->next;
            free(item);
            item = temp;
        }
```

Same goes for the outer loop.

Aside, code will also benefit from an `insert` function.

Comment: I made a change as follows:
```
void free_lists(List *list)
{
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while (list != NULL)
        {
            List *temp = list->next;

            Item *item = list->first_item;
            while (item != NULL)
            {
                Item *temp = item->next;
                free(item);
                item = temp;
            }

            free(list);
            list = temp;
        }
    }
}
```
it did not fix the issue however.

Comment: @MohammadAslam How did you determine that it didn't fix the issue?

Comment: Maybe you tried printing again and you expected nothing to show? If that's the case, the behavior is undefined, in other words you might get the items you have previously stored or you might get an error or you might get something completely unexpected.

Comment: You are right, I changed the function now a bit more so that I can modify the pointers, now after I free the memory I also set that pointer to NULL and now my print function does not print anything. Thank you for your help!